# How to write a Jasmine custom matcher

Tags: javascript, testing, jasmine, matcher

I am trying to write a Custom Matcher that tests if a string contains a special number of occurrences of a different string. This is what I did.

```
var matcher = {
    toContainTimes: function (expected, num) {
        return {
            compare: function(actual){
                actual.match(new RegExp(expected, "g") || []).length == num;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But I get an error when executing this:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'pass' of undefined
```

My test looks like this:

```
expect(queryString).toContainTimes("&", 2);
```

It should return true if the string "&" occurs exactly twice in queryString.
What did I do wrong?

Comment: You don't `return` anything from your matcher.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [Jasmine](http://jasmine.github.io/2.3/custom_matcher.html) docs:

> The compare function must return a result **object** with a **pass**
>   property that is a **boolean** result of the matcher. The pass
>   property tells the expectation whether the matcher was successful
>   (true) or unsuccessful (false).

You should return an object with such properties declared.

Try this:

```
var matcher: {
    toContainTimes: function () {
        return {
            compare: function(actualValue, expectedResult){
                var expected = expectedResult[0];
                var num = expectedResult[1];
                var result = {
                    pass: true,
                    message: ''
                }
                result.pass = actualValue.match(new RegExp(expected, "g") || []).length === num;

                if(!result.pass)
                    result.message = 'insert error message here. this will shown when the jasmine spec failed';

                return result;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Usage: `expect(queryString).toContainTimes(["&", 2]);`